# MySQL Query WHERE combination of AND and OR

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get all entries in a table which belong to "parent_id" (7 OR 8 OR 9 OR 10) AND 3 AND 14.

The following is pseudo code. What do I need to change in order to get it working?

```
SELECT news_id
FROM news_categories
WHERE 
    category_id IN (7,8,9,10) 
AND (
    category_id IN (3,14)
    GROUP BY news_id
    HAVING COUNT(category_id) = 2
)
```

Thanks in advance for every hint which brings me on my way ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT news_id
FROM news_categories
GROUP BY news_id
HAVING sum(category_id IN (7,8,9,10)) > 0
and sum(category_id = 3) > 0
and sum(category_id = 14) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Select news_id 
from (
Select news_Id,category_Id from news_categories where (category_Id in(7,8,9,10))and category_id=3 and category_id=14) 
group by news_id
Having count(category_id)=2 ;